# Как реализовать фильтр слов?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица "фразы" с полем "фраза".
Есть таблица "фильтр" с полем "слово".
(образно все на русском)

Как сделать выборку фраз начинающихся на "Ре", чтобы из этого списка фраз были исключены фразы, в которых встерчается любой из слов таблицы "фильтр".

select фраза from фразы where фраза like 'Ре%' .... и как прикрутить фильтр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
select phrase from phrases where phrase like 'Ре%' and phrase 
not in(
select phrase from phrases p join words w
on p.phrase like concat('%', w.word, '%') 
)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Подскажите какие еще лучше индексы добавить для ускорения выбоки? Добавил отдельно на поле phrase, отдельно на поле word. Всеравно запрос занимает 0.6 сек. Стоит ли еще какие-нибудь составные индексы делать для большей скорости?

Comment: Кроме индекса по phrase вряд ли какой еще ускорит этот запрос.
Подзапрос не будет использовать поиск по индексу, поскольку слово может находиться в любом месте фразы.
Ускорить могло бы изменение структуры, если разбить фразы на слова, и хранить, помимо фразы целиком, еще и слова, из которых она состоит.

Comment: Еще интересует такой вопрос: возможно ли делать подобную выборку фраз с фильтром при помощи полнотекстового поиска? Эфективнее ли это и быстрее?

Comment: С полнотекстовым поиском я не работал.
Экспериментируйте.

Comment: @alex-v, _полнотекстовый поиск_ для этого и придуман.

Comment: с тем лишь отличием, что он ищет именно слова, а не куски подстрок в словах (если я не ошибаюсь)